# Perl: Fastest match of anything?

Tags: regex, performance, perl

I want to do this without using /s:

```
(?:.|\n)+
```

And I want it to be fast.

It is part of a bigger regexp, which is the reason I cannot use /s. I have tested:

```
perl -pe 's/(?:.|\n)+//'  #  30 MBytes/s
perl -pe 's/[^\777]+//'   # 124 MBytes/s
```

They are not as fast as /s:

```
perl -pe 's/.+//s'        # 164 MBytes/s
```

Can I somehow get the same speed as /s?

Edit:

```
perl -pe 's/(?s).+(?-s)//' # 162 MBytes/s
perl -pe 's/[\d\D]+//'    # 162 MBytes/s
perl -pe 's/[\s\S]+//'    # 161 MBytes/s
```

These are all good options. Thanks.

Comment: What about `[\d\D]` or `[\s\S]` etc.?

Comment: Re the edit `(?s:.)` and the ones you listed are result in exactly the same regex program, so they'll all perform identically. `[\d\D]` and `[\s\S]` are workarounds, and only work in since 5.24, so these are the worse options. And `(?s:.)` is better than `(?s).+(?-s)` because it restores the `s` flag instead of turning it off. (It's also shorter.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I create a 98MB file:

```
$ dd bs=1024 count=100000 </dev/urandom >file
100000+0 records in
100000+0 records out
102400000 bytes transferred in 0.558640 secs (183302305 bytes/sec)
```

Now compare some methods:

```
time perl -0777 -lne 's/(?:.|\n)+//' file 
real    0m1.957s
user    0m1.902s
sys 0m0.050s

time perl -0777 -lne 's/[^\777]+//' file 
real    0m0.130s
user    0m0.082s
sys 0m0.046s

time perl -0777 -lne 's/[\s\S]+//' file 
real    0m0.065s
user    0m0.022s
sys 0m0.041s

time perl -0777 -lne 's/.+//s'  file 
real    0m0.064s
user    0m0.022s
sys 0m0.038s
```

As you can see, the character class of `[\s\S]` is optimized to `/./s` since 5.24.

```
$ perl -Mre=debug -e'qr/./s'
Compiling REx "."
Final program:
   1: SANY (2)
   2: END (0)
minlen 1
Freeing REx: "."

$ perl -Mre=debug -e'qr/[\s\S]/'
Compiling REx "[\s\S]"
Final program:
   1: SANY (2)
   2: END (0)
minlen 1
Freeing REx: "[\s\S]"
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use anyworkarounds.

You may use inline modifier flags, `(?s)` to enable dot to match across lines and `(?-s)` to disable this effect.

For example:

```perl
(?s).*PATTERN(?-s).*
```

where the first `.*` matches any text and the last `.*` only matches till the end of a line.

You can also use modifier groups:

```perl
(?s:.*)PATTERN(?-s:.*)
```

See more in [*Extended Patterns*](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Extended-Patterns).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `(?s:PATTERN)` to enable `/s` for just the subpattern in the parens.

```regex
(?s:.)+
```

or

```regex
(?s:.+)
```

For example,

```
$ perl -M5.010 -e'
   say /^.(?s:.).\z/ ? "match" : "no match"
      for "\n\n\n", "A\n\n", "\n\nA", "A\nA";
'
no match
no match
no match
match
```

There is no difference between `.` with `/s` and `(?s:.)`, so you'll get exactly the same performance.

```
$ perl -Mre=debug -e'qr/(?s:.)/'
Compiling REx "(?s:.)"
Final program:
   1: SANY (2)
   2: END (0)
minlen 1
Freeing REx: "(?s:.)"

$ perl -Mre=debug -e'qr/./s'
Compiling REx "."
Final program:
   1: SANY (2)
   2: END (0)
minlen 1
Freeing REx: "."
```

Advantages over the other solutions:

- `(?s:.)` restores the `s` flag state, while `(?s).(?-s)` turns it off.
- `(?s:.)` is a fair bit shorter than `(?s).(?-s)`.
- `(?s:.)` is not longer than `[\s\S]` and `[\d\D]`.
- `(?s:.)` is not a workaround like `[\s\S]` and `[\d\D]`.

That said, `(?s:.)`, `(?s).(?-s)`, `[\s\S]` and `[\d\D]` all result in exactly the same regex program (since 5.24), so they'll all perform identically.